# Working with chars and strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, char

I'm writing a C# program that works with chars and strings.

```
String str= textbox1.text;
if(str[0]="'")
{
}
```

How I can use "'" in my if statement?

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this, escape `'` with `\`

```
'\''
```

and `==`

```
String str= textbox1.text;
if(str[0]=='\'')
{

}
```